In the perfectly coupled transformer, there is no voltage induced in the primary due to the loaded secondary?
When the coils of a transformer are perfectly coupled, the equations include only the self induced emf in the primary and the mutually induced emf in the secondary. However, when speaking of loosely coupled transformer, the equations mention that besides the self induced emf in the primary, there is a mutually induced component by the secondary. I am wondering, why only is this mentioned when talking loosely coupled? I mean isn't there a mutually induced emf in the primary due to the secondary in the perfectly coupled transformer?

Your first two sentences seem to be saying the same thing. Could you be more specific -- include the equations you're referring to, and a schematic, perhaps?


isn't there a mutually induced emf in the primary due to the secondary
in the perfectly coupled transformer?

No there isn't.
In a perfectly coupled transformer, secondary-load ampere-turns are cancelled out by the primary ampere-turns that are needed to supply current to the secondary load. The effect of this is that flux in the core remains wholly determined by the magnetization current in the primary.
When coupling is less than unity, a transformer primary can be said to have "leakage inductance" and, this will produce volt-drops due to secondary load currents.

flux in the core surely remains wholly determined by the total magnetising current in the transformer, algebraic sum of primary and secondary currents. 'Magnetisiation current in the primary', if you define it to mean this, could be this, but I'm sure it will confuse the noobs. I know you know what you mean, and I can sort of see your grain of truth in there, but please be more precise and so noob friendly. It is difficult to infer the OP's mindset from this labrinthine question, in order to tackle just that.

Well I'm confused/baffled by your comment @Neil

@Andyaka but in order to increase the primary current to produce th flux that cancel out the secondary flux, the original AC source needs a support. Looking around, there seems to be nowhere this support can be provided unless the secondary induces a an emf in the primary in the same direction as the source?

@Jack please be accurate in your terminology; the secondary doesn't induce anything unless there is a secondary current. What do you mean by "support"?

By support, I mean the emf of the source must increase in order to increase the primary current in order to cancel out the flux produced by the current in the secondary coil.

My question is how would the source emf increase unless there is an induced emf- in the same direction as the AC source- added to the picture induced in the primary by the current in the secondary?

@Jack the source voltage will remain the same value. Current is drawn into the primary to ensure energy conservation or, transformers just wouldn't work.

@Andyaka the current is drown from the same soucre, but its value nevertheless increases in response to the secondary current. Got it, thanks Andy!

@Andyaka I have one last question Andy. How does the primary current knows that it should increase?

@Jack that's kind of difficult to explain on a simple step other than by observing that conservation of energy must take place. Maybe if you think about why two coils coupled together having different numbers of turns are fundamentally an impedance transformer. In other words, a 10 ohm resistor across an ideal secondary will look like a 1000 ohm on the primary of a 10:1 step down device. Impedance transformation is proportional to turns ratio squared.

If an ideal transformer is excited by an ideal AC voltage source, then voltage across the primary is completely determined by that ideal AC voltage source. Rather than inducing a voltage in the primary, one might say that the current in the secondary induces a current in the primary. In an ideal transformer, excited by an ideal AC voltage source, the current in the primary times the number of turns in the primary is equal to the current in the secondary times the number of turns in the secondary. The fluxes that would be induced by either of these currents are in opposite directions, and their magnitudes would be equal. As a result, they cancel, and the net flux in this ideal transformer is 0.
The case where a transformer is excited by an ideal AC voltage source is the "usual" case one thinks of when considering a transformer. However, a transformer can alternatively be excited by an AC current source. In that case it is generally called a current transformer. In fact, what makes a transformer a current transformer is that it's primary is excited by an AC current rather than an AC voltage.
If an ideal transformer is excited by an ideal AC current, the exciting source does not fix the primary voltage. As a result, current in the secondary does indeed affect the the primary voltage. However, the relationship may not be immediately intuitive. In any ideal transformer, the voltage across the primary divided by the number of primary turns is equal to the voltage across the secondary divided by the number of secondary turns. So what is the voltage across the secondary in a transformer whose primary is excited by a current source? That depends on the current in the secondary and the burden or load attached to the secondary. If an ideal resistor is attached to the secondary, one can use Ohm's law to calculate the secondary voltage. Similarly if any linear impedance is used. However, the secondary's burden or load has a non-linear voltage-current relationship, the voltages on both the primary and secondary will not be pure sine waves, even though the exciting current may be a pure sine wave.

You said "In an ideal transformer, excited by an ideal AC voltage source, the current in the primary times the number of turns in the primary is equal to the current in the secondary times the number of turns in the secondary. The fluxes that would be induced by either of these currents are in opposite directions, and their magnitudes would be equal. As a result, they cancel, and the net flux in this ideal transformer is 0." However, before this could happen, the primary current was very low, the magnetizing current. How did that current increase, something must have helped?!
